# How much data is needed for good ROC?

Tags: roc, large-data

I am working on 2 class classification problem. I have over 1 million data points for each class available and I am building the Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) curve to evaluate classifiers. But 1 million data points looks like much more than what is really needed.

How much data should I sample to get a good ROC? Which principle could lead me?

Comment: There are some versions of main theorems in statistics that also give you a rate of convergence but honestly: they require additional assumptions, they are rather clumsy and they give you complicated result that you would have to translate to the ROC language. My approach would be to try with 10,100,1000,5000,10000,20000,100000,... samples and see when the curve stabilizes.